# Android Share cache between webView

Tags: java, android, caching, webview

In my app the user can view some news page with a lot of images. When the user read a page in  a webview, the app in background loads the images of the second page in a second webview. So when the user load the 2nd page images are already in the cache and the 1st webview can load them. This is valid in the iOS version of my app.
In the android version I can't do that. It seems that the 2 webview have got a separate cache. Infact if the user try to reload the 1st page (already loaded with the 1st webview) images are loaded from the cache.

Comment: check this link, might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128952/caching-in-android-webview

Comment: already viewed before posting my question my it seems that viewer.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/com.your.package.appname/cache"‌​); doesn't work.

Comment: How did you resolve this?