# How to cache WebView content in Android?

Tags: android, caching, webview

In my Android app I need to cache the (already loaded) content of WebView on pause and then restore it on resume. I wonder how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried calling webview.onPause() and webview.onResume() ??

Comment: please view link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128952/caching-in-android-webview

Comment: Thanks for replies. I'll try both suggestions and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It is cached automatically unless you disable. Nothing special needs to be done.

A common problem is that badly designed parent resets the view itself in methods like `onStart` or `onResume`, forcing to reload the contents. You need to be careful with the view in these methods, it may already with content.

Comment: Audrius thanks for your answer. Did you mean that I shouldn't implement those methods of the view?

Comment: No, just think that are you doing in these methods.